# How to get unity container defined in unity config from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I am trying to configure Microsoft unity in Mvc application

I have defined unity configuration in unity.config:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer(); 
        container.RegisterType<IAccessLogBLL, AccessLogBLL>();            
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

I call that configuration from global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();


    }
```

Now I have define that container an its configuration from controller before call to resolve method and works fine, but how can I use the container defined in unity.config ? 
Is there any "getContainer" method or I have to declare global variable for unity container?

```
   private IAccessLogBLL _accessLogBLL;
   public AccessLogController()
    {

        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();            
        container.RegisterType<IAccessLogBLL, AccessLogBLL>();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        _accessLogBLL = container.Resolve<IAccessLogBLL>(new ParameterOverride("unitOfWork", UnitOfWork));
    }
```

Thanks and sorry about my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finallly I declare container variable static and it works fine. But I don´t now that it is the best solution.

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static IUnityContainer container;
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        container = new UnityContainer(); 
        container.RegisterType<IAccessLogBLL, AccessLogBLL>();            
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

And form my controller constructor:

```
public AccessLogController()
    {

        _accessLogBLL = UnityConfig.container.Resolve<IAccessLogBLL>(new ParameterOverride("unitOfWork", UnitOfWork));

    }
```

Comment: That approach is fine, but I would use [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) to ensure thread safety.  For example: `private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            /* register your types here */

            return container;
        });`

Comment: You can then choose an appropriate [thread safety mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I will check your advice